# VirtueMart Children Product List

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Hey I'm trying to style a list of children products I have. These children products are displayed in a dropdown and from there their attributes are displayed. I need to restyle this children product list, or reformat it so it's not a dropdown. This would be easy but I can't find where this list is built for the life of me.

If anyone out there is familiar enough with Virtuemart for Joomla 1.5 any direction would be amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shane,

VM is an ungainly mess to navigate thru, but I **think** the file you're looking for is this one:

```
/components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/common/categoryChildlist.tpl.php
```

That's assuming you're using the "default" theme, but if you're using a custom theme, I think it's in the same relative location.